# How to update Watch app from an iOS extension, when containing app is not running at all

Tags: ios, watchkit, ios-extensions, background-fetch, remote-notifications

I have an iOS app and Action extension that share data via a UserDefaults common to an App Group.

When a user adds model data using the action extension, and the iOS app is in the background, I can use KVO to observe the UserDefaults key in question, and kick off a background refresh of the Watch app - this works great.

However, what about if the app is not in the background, but completely inactive? KVO obviously isn't going to happen. The iOS app will pick up the changes to UserDefaults when it next launches (manually or via background refresh) and propagate these to the watch, but in the meantime the Watch data is out of sync until its next refresh.

The only way I can think to solve this is to have the Action Extension kick off a remote, silent notification pushed to the iOS app, which then does a background refresh to the watch. But it seems a little... heavy handed? to go via the web for an app and its extension sitting on the same device.

What's the solution I'm missing?